# What does this schematic mean?

Tags: multiplexer, symbol

I know that this is a 4:1 MUX, but what does the little line across the w1 w2 selection line mean?

You know, the little black line that has a "2" next to it.

Has it something to do with "array" or something?

[image]

Comment: You can also think about it as 2^n and you have 4 input lines.  n must be 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This notation means a *bus* line with the width noted by the number written next to it. In your case it is 2-bit wide bus. It is used to make the drawing less convoluted by reducing lines drawn.

Comment: Okay, so instead of drawing a selection for both w1 and w2, you can just draw a bus line like this, and indicate how many lines it represents?

Comment: Yes, this is what it does.